# Can't unregister parent theme's CPT from my child theme

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks, actions

Here's how I create my CPT in my parent theme's `functions.php`:

```
function my_custom_post_job() {
  ...
  register_post_type('job', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'my_custom_post_job');
```

I'm trying to unregister this in my child theme's `functions.php` like so:

```
add_action('init', 'remove_cpt');
function remove_cpt() {
  remove_action('init', 'my_custom_post_job');
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Child theme functions.php is loaded before parent.

Comment: So that's not doable then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot remove a hook when you are in the same hook with the same priority.

a solution is to hook the action with a lower priority

```
add_action('init', 'remove_cpt', 5);
```

Comment: If the parent theme hook is declared without a priority then the default is 10, so the hook to remove it will need to be higher than 10.

Comment: if the function `remove_cpt` is run after `my_custom_post_job`, it's too late to remove it. my answer has been tested and is shipped with a mmm's certification of conformity and a 5 years warranty ;)

Comment: Oh I see `remove_cpt` is removing the init hook, not detrgistering the post type.